# How to construct a dual interface/value in Typescript without declaring Class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-class

In Typescript, declaring a `class` magically creates both an interface and a value. But creating a class value through other means does not automatically make it a type, so e.g.

```ts
class Normal<T> {}
const Derived = Normal<number>

let normal: Normal<number> // <-- Fine and normal
let derived: Derived // <-- Derived is not a type
```

Somewhat amazingly, I discovered you can simply merge a type onto the value to manually mimic the class declaration, e.g.:

```ts
class Normal<T> {}
const Derived = Normal<number>
type Derived = Normal<number>

let normal: Normal<number> // <-- Fine and normal
let derived: Derived // <-- Now also fine
```

My question is this: If `Derived` is created dynamically, is there a way to get this dual interface/value without manually adding steps, e.g.

```ts
class Normal<T> {}

function derive<T>(generic: T) {
    const Derived = Normal<T>
    type Derived = Normal<T> // obviously will not work
    return Derived
}

const Derived = derive(number)

let normal: Normal<number>
let derived: Derived // <-- Derived is not a type
```

The context is I'm providing an API that creates many such classes and adds dynamic generics. I want to simplify the use of these classes for the API consumer.

Comment: No, you cannot automagically declare types this way. There have been declined suggestions which would make something like this happen (see [ms/TS#18942](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18942) for example).  For now if you don't want to use a `class` declaration [like this for example](https://tsplay.dev/m0exRW) then you will have to manually create the type name. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I believe so. Thanks for linking that issue. I hadn't seen it. If this 7 year old issue is indeed the last of it, then it's answered. Since this issue seems to predate `InstanceType` I'm guessing that `InstanceType` was in a way an answer to questions raised there, although it doesn't fully address my request. Is that fair?

Comment: Right, `InstanceType<typeof Derived>` should work but it's not what you're asking for and can't be abstracted over (there's no way to write `type X<v> = InstanceType<typeof v>` because type aliases can't act on values, only types).  There might be newer issues requesting something that would give you what you want, but nothing has implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get a class instance type to be declared without explicitly creating the type yourself is with a `class` declaration ([relevant doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts)). There was a feature request a while ago at [microsoft/TypeScript#18942](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18942) so that any named value whose type is a class constructor would automatically also cause an instance type of the same name to exist, but this was declined.

Unless you're willing to write an actual class declaration such as

```
class Derived extends Normal<number> { }
```

then the only way to get a named type corresponding to your named value is to declare it separately as you discovered:

```
const Derived = Normal<number>
type Derived = Normal<number>
```

(Note that this is not considered [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html); named types and named values live in different spaces that do not conflict. Declaration merging is when you refer to the same named value multiple times or the same named type multiple times.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEByD2AnAtmEAeAKgPmgb2gF8AoUSGAEQFNEBLANyoBNoqAPAFyoDsmYEUadNwCuyAEY1cBEsRBUO0bklQgAXHBVDREqXIXQmNBsw3U6jFsSA)

Comment: As a follow-up, while I understand how that's technically different than declaration merging, what I found cool was that I could then `export Derived` and export *both* the value and type as if it were a normal class declaration. Feels kind of like they're merged when you do that.